Resolving Scoped Services Dynamically in ASP.NET Core
In my ASP.NET Core application, I have a scenario where I need to dynamically resolve scoped services within a factory to handle different operations. Here's an overview of my current setup and the issue I'm facing:
I have a controller MyController that relies on a handler MyHandler to perform create and get operations. The MyHandler class has dependencies on two scoped services: IDatabaseService and IThirdPartyService.
However, the MyHandler.Get() method does not require IThirdPartyService. Despite this, when using dependency injection, an instance of IThirdPartyService is still injected into the handler.
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IMyHandler _handler;

    public MyController(IMyHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
    {
        _handler.Create(model);
        return Ok();
    } 
    
    public ActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var model = _handler.Get(id);
        return Ok(model);
    } 
}

public class MyHandler : IHandler
{
    private readonly IDatabaseService _dbService;
    private readonly IThirdPartyService _service;

    public MyHandler(IDatabaseService dbService, IThirdPartyService service)
    {
        _dbService = dbService;
        _service = service;
    }
    
    public void Create(MyModel model)
    {
        _dbService.Create(model);
        _service.Create(model);
    }
    
    public MyModel Get(int id)
    {
        _dbService.Get(id);     
    }
}

MyHandler is registred as scoped service with DI.
To address this issue, I'm considering creating a factory (HandlerFactory) that dynamically resolves scoped services. This factory would be registered as a singleton and used to resolve the appropriate handler instance based on the operation. I'm considering creating two new handlers: MyHandlerCreate and MyHandlerGet. Each handler would be responsible for its specific operations, and only the required dependencies would be injected.
Then, I would use the HandlerFactory to resolve the appropriate handler instance in the controller action methods.
public class HandlerFactory : IHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public HandlerFactory(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public T Get<T>() where T : IHandler
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();    
        }
    }
}

public class MyHandlerGet:IHandler
{
    private IDatabaseService _dbService;

    public MyHandlerGet(IDatabaseService dbService)
    {
       _dbService= dbService;
    }
    
    public MyModel Get(int id)
    {
       _dbService.Get(id);   
    }
}

public class MyHandlerCreate:IHandler
{
    private IDatabaseService _dbService;
    provate IThirdPartyService _service;

    public MyHandlerCreate(IDatabaseService dbService, IThirdPartyService service)
    {
       _dbService= dbService;
       _service = service;
    }
    
    public void Create(MyModel model)
    {
       _dbService.Create(model);
       _service.Create(model);
    }
}

Both MyHandlerGet and MyHandlerCreate will be register as scoped services with DI.
then in controller action method I can simply resolve the instance of handler that is specific to the request, for example
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var handler = _factory.Get<MyHandlerGet>();
    var model= await handler.Get(id);
    return Ok(model);
}

My questions are:

Is injecting IServiceScopeFactory into another factory considered an anti-pattern?
Is there a better alternative solution to dynamically resolve scoped services?
Am I on the right track with my proposed solution, or is there a more optimal approach to handle this scenario?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Check out this solution. We are using it for a few years now and it's great. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/238506/224952

Will start from few notes. The following:
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();    
}

Can have at least the following problems:

if T is disposable or depends on disposable services controlled by the scope they will be disposed with the scope itself (i.e. at the end of the using block). This can be worked around by creating a disposable wrapper as for example here and then the wrapper is disposed "manually" by the caller, which follows the approach taken by framework provided factories (IHttpClientFactory or DbContext one)

The scope will differ from the request one, so if you have some scoped "shared" dependency which should be the same for the T and the rest of the request processing you will have problems.


As for the question itself. It seems that you are overcomplicating things here. ASP.NET Core supports service injection into controller actions and Minimal API handlers. So you can just inject them directly into the action:
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, [FromServices] MyHandlerGet handler)
{
    var model = await handler.Get(id);
    return Ok(model);
}

Based on the provided info - no need for factory here.
Alternatively you can add Lazy/Func registration (it is not provided out of the box but still). Minimalistic one could look like the following:
services.AddScoped<Lazy<object>>(sp => new Lazy<object>(sp.GetRequiredService<object>));

And then resolve appropriate Lazy/Func in the ctor and get value from it when needed.
